# Elasticsearch: exists filter not working

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is my data ...

```
{"score":60,"name":"bill"},
{"score":50,"name":"john"},
{"score":null,"name":"sam"}
```

I am looking to write a filter range query, which should also INCLUDE null values.

I tried this ... and expecting all 3 results, but it returned 0 results ... ?

```
"filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "range": {
                    "score": {
                      "lte": 100
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "exists": {
                    "field": "score"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
```

Any help is very appreciated ...
Thanks

Comment: can you paste the return message as well?

Comment: @MedAli Not sure what do you mean ? There is no error .... It just returned 0 results

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is that have a `bool/should` with either your `range` query or a missing `score` field

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "range": {
            "score": {
              "lte": 100
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": {
              "exists": {
                "field": "score"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```